# Wireless not connected on Ubuntu 15.04 using tplink tl wn823n adapter

Tags: wireless, network-manager

My wired internet connection is working but wireless is not. I can see wireless networks but when try to connect it just doesn't connect. After I tried several things it finally connected once, but the speed was so poor that it almost wasn't working at all. I tried approaches from

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD
- https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD#Reverting_to_NetworkManager

After installing WICD I was not able to see any network icon, usually on desktop screen top right corner. Ubuntu stopped detecting the wifi adapter. After I revoked the switch to WICD, I am back to the the original situation.

I'm able to see wireless networks. I don't think this is an authentication problem (password encryption on router and Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

Here is How I fixed it.
My Lenovo ideapad Y560 has an internal intel centerino 1000BGN wireless adapter. This adapter does not work on Windows and I am using a TPlink 823N USB adapter. In Linux, due to intel chipset, Ubuntu loads iwlDvm, which is first layer driver to detect Wifi, then `iwlwifi` driver to use to connect to it.

I need only `iwldvm` to recognize the wireless networks; I have no need of `iwlwifi`.

I reinstalled Ubuntu and this time I just blacklisted the iwlwifi driver and restarted.

Here are the commands:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist iwlwifi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r iwlwifi
exit
```

Now I am able to connect to wifi network. I think there's still a problem as connection drops after some time. But it has been partially fixed. I think I have to get the realtek driver package and then it will work fully.